# This Variation code doesn't work with my code in doStuff Function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to fetch the data from  the sheet cell B1 and do the math with that data but it doesn't work when I this line

```
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1mkbnIlDt6WGltQg6peKojBFPz0JwyjAkJGwTYbLYEmk').getSheetByName('HardEdit').getRange('B1').getValue();
```

But when i remove the above line, it works all fine.can i know the reasone?  here is my code,

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
    function doStuff() {
     
      var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1mkbnIlDt6WGltQg6peKojBFPz0JwyjAkJGwTYbLYEmk').getSheetByName('HardEdit').getRange('B1').getValue(); //Separate spreadsheet book
 
      const rate = 0.155;
      const vprice = document.getElementById("price").value;
      const downPayment = document.getElementById("DownPay").value;
      const borrow = vprice-downPayment;
      const period = 12;// add motnhs here
      const opp = vprice*0.5;
     
      
      var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat(); //number format 
     
     const subL = Math.round((vprice*source)/2);
```

Comment: In your situation, where is the script including `doStuff()`? It's in the Google Apps Script project? Or it's in the file on your local PC?

Comment: @Tanaike it's in the Google Apps Script Project.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on your console?

Comment: You can view my script on this link https://script.google.com/d/1M9YYZIGXpOvmMZ9ESEh14HYfbshEoV9s9YqarYSg1qh8pEyV4G-Ki3rj/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Tanaike It worked :) Thank you. In case If i want to pull another data from C1, what should be done?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, when you want to retrieve the values from the cells "B1:C1" to Javascript side, please modify `getRange('B1').getValue()` to `getRange('B1:C1').getValues()[0]` and `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(source => {` to `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(values => {var b1 = values[0]; var c1 = values[1]`. By this, `b1` and `c1` are the values from the cells "B1" and "C1", respectively.

Comment: @Tanaike If I want to get data from e.g. A1,B2,C10,D20 how do i set the range?

Comment: At first, can I ask you whether your 2nd question was resolved? And, about your 3rd question of `If I want to get data from e.g. A1,B2,C10,D20 how do i set the range?`, in that case, how about retrieving the cell "A1:A2", "C10", "D20" and returning the values to Javascript side?

Comment: Yes the second question is resolved, the third question is, the data can be any part of the sheet cell, I'll try the way you've put it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, at HTML&Javascript side (client side), Google Apps Script cannot be directly used. In your case, I think that `google.script.run` can be used for retrieving the values from Google Apps Script. So please modify as follows.

#### HTML&Javascript side:

Please modify `doStuff()` as follows.

```
function doStuff() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(source => {
    const rate = 0.155;
    const vprice = document.getElementById("price").value;
    const downPayment = document.getElementById("DownPay").value;
    const borrow = vprice-downPayment;
    const period = 12;// add motnhs here
    const opp = vprice*0.5;
    var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat(); //number format 
    const subL = Math.round((vprice*source)/2);
  }).getValues();
}
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please add the following function.

```
function getValues() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.openById('1mkbnIlDt6WGltQg6peKojBFPz0JwyjAkJGwTYbLYEmk').getSheetByName('HardEdit').getRange('B1').getValue();
}
```

- In this modification, when `doStuff()` is run, `getValues()` at Google Apps Script is run by `google.script.run`. And the returned value from `getValues()` can be retrieved at Javascript side using `withSuccessHandler`.

#### References:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)